# Общественный транспорт в виждете

Tags: яндекс-карты

Подскажите можно ли отрисовать движущийся транспорт на карте у себя на сайте?
Например как тут https://yandex.ru/maps/9/lipetsk/transport/?from=api-maps&ll=39.581041%2C52.595573&origin=jsapi_2_1_74&z=14